# Is there a python binding to the Berkeley DB XML database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-xml

I'm trying to migrate some perl code to python and it uses `Sleeypcat::DbXml 'simple'` to get read access to a `.dbxml` file, creates a `XmlManager`, calls `createQueryContext`, `openContainer` and `query` to get an `XmlValue`.  I have found https://pypi.org/project/berkeleydb/ to support the Berkeley DB in general, but it has no mention of this XML layer.  Is there an existing API I can use in python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berkeley dbxml does come with a Pyhon bindings.  I ended up having to make modifications to the [SWIG](https://www.swig.org/) interface files to get it to run with Python3.  If you are interested in building for a recent Python, you will need to make some modifications to the Python interface file.  Specifically, you have to

- redefine PYSTR_* macros to use unicode strings
- make changes to the initialization code to return the module
- update the Python 3 iterator code to use __next__ via a %rename pragma
- potentially add code for missing objects an changed interfaces, e.g. I added an XmlResultsIterator, and added som code to XmlManager to let me reindex containers.

You then need to regenerate the swig interface and recompile the module. I don't know StackOverflow's policy on posting patches, but if it's allowed I'd be happy to post the patches that I created for dbxml 6.1.4 and Python 3.9 for you. Getting it all compiled is a little bit of work, but very doable.

Comment: I'd certainly be interested in the patch - snoopyjc AT gmail DOT com please

Answer (score 1):

Berkeley DB and Berkeley DB XML are two different products. My python bindings (legacy "bsddb3" and current "berkeleydb") only interface with Berkeley DB.

I am not aware of any Python bindings for Berkeley DB XML.

I am a freelance with commercial contracts, if that option would be useful to you.